# Get a histogram plot of factor frequencies (summary)

Tags: r, plot, histogram, frequency-distribution

I've got a factor with many different values. If you execute `summary(factor)` the output is a  list of the different values and their frequency. Like so:

```
A B C D
3 3 1 5
```

I'd like to make a histogram of the frequency values, i.e. X-axis contains the different frequencies that occur, Y-axis the number of factors that have this particular frequency. What's the best way to accomplish something like that?

edit: thanks to the answer below I figured out that what I can do is get the factor of the frequencies out of the table, get that in a table and then graph that as well, which would look like (if `f` is the factor):

```
plot(factor(table(f)))
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Update in light of clarified Q**

```
set.seed(1)
dat2 <- data.frame(fac = factor(sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = TRUE)))
hist(table(dat2), xlab = "Frequency of Level Occurrence", main = "")
```

gives:

[image: histogram of frequency of occurrence in factor]

Here we just apply `hist()` directly to the result of `table(dat)`. `table(dat)` provides the frequencies per level of the factor and `hist()` produces the histogram of these data.

---

**Original**

There are several possibilities. Your data:

```
dat <- data.frame(fac = rep(LETTERS[1:4], times = c(3,3,1,5)))
```

Here are three, from column one, top to bottom:

- The default plot methods for class `"table"`, plots the data and histogram-like bars
- A bar plot - which is probably what you meant by histogram. Notice the low ink-to-information ratio here
- A dot plot or dot chart; shows the same info as the other plots but uses far less ink per unit information. Preferred.

Code to produce them:

```
layout(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
plot(table(dat), main = "plot method for class \"table\"")
barplot(table(dat), main = "barplot")
tab <- as.numeric(table(dat))
names(tab) <- names(table(dat))
dotchart(tab, main = "dotchart or dotplot")
## or just this
## dotchart(table(dat))
## and ignore the warning
layout(1)
```

this produces:

[image: one dimensional plots]

If you just have your data in variable `factor` (bad name choice by the way) then `table(factor)` can be used rather than `table(dat)` or `table(dat$fac)` in my code examples.

For completeness, package `lattice` is more flexible when it comes to producing the dot plot as we can get the orientation you want:

```
require(lattice)
with(dat, dotplot(fac, horizontal = FALSE))
```

giving:

[image: Lattice dotplot version]

And a `ggplot2` version:

```
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data.frame(Freq = tab, fac = names(tab)), aes(fac, Freq)) + 
    geom_point()
p
```

giving:

[image: ggplot2 version]

Comment: For bonus points, you can reorder the factor levels from smallest to largest. `fac_levels <- levels(dat$fac); o <- order(table(dat$fac)); dat$fac <- with(dat, factor(fac, levels = fac_levels[o]))`.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough in my question. I know how to do this. What I want to do is count how many factors have a frequency of 1, how many have a frequency of 2, 3, ... and then plot that on a barchart (basically, this is a histogram if you bin it). Perhaps the fact that it is in a factor is not ideal but that's how it came out of `read.csv`. So what I want is a chart showing the frequencies of the frequencies.

Comment: @wds Is that more like what you want?

Comment: that is awesome thanks. I'd like to actually turn this into a barchart, maybe with a logarithmic y axis to highlight outliers but I guess that is a different question entirely.

Comment: And the original answer was really helpful in analysing it further, thanks again.