# How to make a barplot with data where one of the columns already contains the frequencies/counts

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot the number of samples that have data for for each of several traits. I actually already have a column of data containing these numbers of samples, and was simply hoping to plot it as the "frequency". As it is, I'm not quite sure where the frequency data is coming from (see code below). Please let me know whether I can clarify anything. Many thanks!:

```
##my data
data<-structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("593", "QnWeight_initial"
), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("566", 
"Head"), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("535", 
"V1"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("535", 
"V2"), class = "factor"), V5 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("535", 
"V3"), class = "factor"), V6 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("482", 
"Left_Leg"), class = "factor"), V7 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("474", 
"Left_Antenna"), class = "factor"), V8 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("237", 
"Qn_Weight_Loss"), class = "factor"), V9 = structure(c(2L, 1L
), .Label = c("230", "Days_wrkr_eclosion"), class = "factor"), 
    V10 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("81", "Growth_all"), class = "factor"), 
    V11 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("79", "Growth_1_2"), class = "factor"), 
    V12 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("62", "Growth_1_3"), class = "factor"), 
    V13 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("60", "Growth_2_3"), class = "factor"), 
    V14 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("51", "Right_Antenna"
    ), class = "factor"), V15 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("49", 
    "Left_Leg_Remeasure"), class = "factor"), V16 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L), .Label = c("49", "Right_Leg"), class = "factor"), V17 = structure(c(2L, 
    1L), .Label = c("47", "Head_Remeasure"), class = "factor"), 
    V18 = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("46", "Left_Antenna_Remeasure"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", 
"V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", 
"V15", "V16", "V17", "V18"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
dat<-data.frame(fac=unlist(data[1,, drop=FALSE]), freqs=unlist(data[2,, drop=FALSE]))
t<-table(rep(as.character(dat[, 1]), dat[, 2]))

##the plot I'm making at the moment
barplot(t, main="Sample Sizes of Various Fitness Traits", xaxt='n', xlab='', width=0.85)
labels<-unlist(data[1,,drop=FALSE])
text(1:18, par("usr")[3] -0.25, srt=90, adj=1,labels=labels,xpd=TRUE, cex=0.6)


##The kind of plot I'm looking to make
par(las=2) # make label text perpendicular to axis
par(mar=c(5,8,4,2)) # increase y-axis margin.

print(mtcars$gear)
counts <- table(mtcars$gear)
print(counts)
barplot(counts, main="Car Distribution", names.arg=c("3 Gears", "4 Gears", "5   Gears"), cex.names=0.8)
```

Comment: Your data is *very* messy. It is not clear where you are getting your numbers (given that you are not using the `Freq` column which you create in `dat`. Everything appears to be a factor. If you input your data with a header, then most of your problems should go away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes an apparently sensible plot. It appears you might be asking how to label a y-axis with "Frequency".

```
barplot( t, main="Sample Sizes of Various Fitness Traits", 
            xaxt='n', xlab='', width=0.85, ylab="Frequency")
labels<-unlist(data[1,,drop=FALSE])
text(1:18, par("usr")[3] -0.25, srt=90, adj=1,labels=labels,xpd=TRUE, cex=0.6)
```

Or:::  Were you asking what the code does because you copied it from someone else and you do not really understand it? The `table` function that creates the object "t" counts up the number of items in the unique categories. The phrase `rep(as.character(dat[, 1]), dat[, 2]))` is a bit obscure but it is repeating each value of V2 the same number of times as is in the numeric coding for the factor representation of V2 in `dat`  .... in other words something more than likely to be nonsense.

Or are you asking if it represents the data in a sensible way? (It does not.) There is an R-FAQ about how to convert factorized variables back to numeric when they have been inadvertently made as such:

```
 barplot( as.numeric( as.character(dat$freqs)) , 
    main="Sample Sizes of Various Fitness Traits", 
    xaxt='n', xlab='', width=0.85, ylab="Frequency")
 labels<-unlist(data[1,,drop=FALSE])
 text(1:18, par("usr")[3] -0.25, srt=90, adj=1,labels=labels,xpd=TRUE, cex=0.6)
```

Comment: DWin, it was the last question. Thank you so much for answering, especially in the context of my messy code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to extract some useful data from your data object. (You problem is that your data columns are all factors with what should be the header row as the first row of the data. This should be able to be fixed using  `read.table(...,header=T)`

```
# converting from factor to character or numeric as required
measure  <- unlist(lapply(data[1,], as.character))
value <- unlist(lapply(data[2,], function(i){as.numeric(as.character(i))}))

# set names appropriately
names(value) <- measure


# the plot
par(las=2) # make label text perpendicular to axis
par(mar=c(5,8,4,2)) # increase y-axis margin.
barplot(value)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, mnel! DWin technically answered my question also, but I learned a lot from your code. Way more elegant than what I was doing. Thank you.